# JUnit assertSame return true with two objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

Why is the following code giving me an error, I'm so confused.

```
@Test
public void testUsers()
{
    User user1 = new User("a");
    User user2 = new User("a");
    assertSame(user1, user2);
}
```

This is the error I am receiving at the moment:

```
expected same:<xxx.xxx.User@615fd9fd> was not:<xxx.xxx.User@5be0a2fc>
java.lang.AssertionError
```

I understand they are difference instances of the same object, but why this error?

Comment: What's the code for `User`?

Comment: Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source code for `assertSame()` is this:

```
static public void assertSame(Object expected, Object actual) {
    assertSame(null, expected, actual);
}

static public void assertSame(String message, Object expected, Object actual) {
    if (expected == actual) {
        return;
    }
    failNotSame(message, expected, actual);
}
```

So `assertSame()` is testing that the provided references point to the *exact same object*, which in your case they are not.

What you want is probably `assertEquals()`:

```
static public void assertEquals(String message, Object expected,
        Object actual) {
    if (equalsRegardingNull(expected, actual)) {
        return;
    } else if (expected instanceof String && actual instanceof String) {
        String cleanMessage = message == null ? "" : message;
        throw new ComparisonFailure(cleanMessage, (String) expected,
                (String) actual);
    } else {
        failNotEquals(message, expected, actual);
    }
}

private static boolean equalsRegardingNull(Object expected, Object actual) {
    if (expected == null) {
        return actual == null;
    }

    return isEquals(expected, actual);
}

private static boolean isEquals(Object expected, Object actual) {
    return expected.equals(actual);
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. When I use assertEquals(user1, user2); it gives me the same error. Any clue why?

Comment: In that case, have you implemented `equals()` in `User`? If you haven't, `expected.equals(actual)` will use `Object#equals()`, which simply returns `expected == actual`, which likely isn't what you wanted.

Comment: No I have not implemented equals in User, do I need to do that when using assertEquals()?

Comment: Yes, you do. As I said, if you have not implemented `equals()`, the default implementation from `Object` will be used for `expected.equals(actual)`, which simply returns `expected == equals`; exactly the same operation that was done in `assertSame()`.

Comment: Thank you I will look into the equals method. The reason I created this question was because of that fact that some of my friends are working on the same assignment and they are claiming that the assertSame is passing... :) thanks.

Comment: No problem. Just keep in mind the difference between *reference equality* and *object equality*. The reason that your friends are getting something different is because they are passing two references to the exact same object into `assertEquals()`. You're passing two references to *different* objects, which will cause the test to fail.

Comment: They are also creating and passing two different objects to the assertSame() and they claim it is passing. That is why I am confused, haha :)

Comment: Hmmm, really? Something's off then, because the source code for `assertSame()` definitely shows that `assertSame()` tests for reference equality... It's confusing for me too. Can't really know what's going on without seeing their code though. I doubt it's a difference in JUnit....

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation. It all workes with an overriden equals method in the user class :-)

Comment: @y451n Glad to hear! Hope you can figure out what's going on with your friends' code. It sounds problematic if supposedly identical code is getting you different results.

Answer (score -2):

You have to implement the equals() and hashCode() on the User object...most of IDEs help you generate it correctly.

Comment: @tbodt Or maybe not... Could be another case of the XY problem.

Comment: Don't rely on the Object's default implementation for the equals and hash Code... In any case, you should implement them, specially if your using collections. ;-)